# Opening files via CLI [PHP]

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
<?php
$file = fopen($argv[0],"r");
echo fgets($file);
fclose($file)
?>
```

Here is my output

```
$ php mail.php test.txt
<?php
```

What i want it to do is display the contents of test.txt.

```
$ ls | grep test.txt
test.txt
```

Just to prove i actually have `test.txt`

I would also like to know how to parse the data from this so, line one would have its own variable.

Answer (score 1):

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

> The first argument $argv[0] is always the name that was used to run
>   the script.

In other words, `$argv[0]` will be the name of your PHP file, `mail.php` in your case (echo it out).  What you want is `$argv[1]` as in `$file = fopen($argv[1],"r");`.

To read the entire file into a string, use `file_get_contents()` (see [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)).

To read the entire file into an array, one line per array entry, use `file()` (see [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)).

Comment: Thanks alot really helped ;)